# Android is not reading full HttpURLConnection InputStream content

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I have the following code that has been tested in Java application class and it **WORKS**
It calls my backend Java servlet and read binary bytes into byte[]

```
private byte[] readResponse(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
    byte[] buffer;
    if (contentLength>-1) {
        buffer = new byte[contentLength];
        int readCount = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer, 0 , contentLength);
        System.out.println("Content Length is " + contentLength + " Read Count is " + readCount);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Now I move this Java code into My Android code, and somehow it only reads the content partially, the server sends roughly 5709 bytes and Android app only reads 1448 bytes

The interesting thing is if I go debug mode and put breakpoint at line

```
int readCount = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer, 0 , contentLength);
```

And do step by step debug, variable

> readCount

can reach 5709 bytes. 
If I didn't put break point, it becomes 1448 bytes.
Why?

It looks like some time delay issue?

Thanks.
Regards,

Comment: You should make a loop and continue reading.

Comment: `System.out.println("Content Length is " + contentLength + " Read Count is " + readCount);
    }`. Well... What is logged? Figures please.

Comment: The print out is 5709 and 1448.
I know the input is 5709 as it is my backend.
As I said if I run the code line by line, I am able to read the whole response into byte array. And there is no network issue as everything is running locally.

Comment: Put the read code in a loop. You got the bytes in chunked. Quite normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone's help, especially user greenapps's answer.
I break the load process into 1kb buffer and resolved the problem.
The following is the code:

```
private byte[] readResponse(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
    byte[] buffer;
    buffer = new byte[contentLength];
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    int bytesRemaining = contentLength;
    int loadedBytes;
    for (int i = 0; i < contentLength; i = i + loadedBytes) {
        int readCount =   bytesRemaining > bufferSize ? bufferSize : bytesRemaining;
        loadedBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, i , readCount);
        bytesRemaining = bytesRemaining - loadedBytes;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
    // Read response
    //int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           response.append(line);
    }

    reader.close();
    response.toString();
```

Comment: The input content is not text string. They are binary bytes that is why I don't want to use bufferedreader to read line into String